# Building PJSIP: error on make with libyuv CentOS

Tags: pjsip

I want to use the pjsip library in CentOS 6 and tried the steps given in getting started page of pjsip.org

I tried to build the pjsip lib by using the following sequence of commands.

```
cd pjproject-2.5.5
./configure
make dep
make
```

After I ran the last command I got following error:

```
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc: In function ‘void libyuv::YuvPixel(uint8, uint8, uint8, uint8*, uint8*, uint8*, const libyuv::YuvConstants*)’:
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1256: erreur: invalid types ‘const signed char __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1257: erreur: invalid types ‘const signed char __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1258: erreur: invalid types ‘const signed char __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1259: erreur: invalid types ‘const signed char __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1260: erreur: invalid types ‘const short int __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1261: erreur: invalid types ‘const short int __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1262: erreur: invalid types ‘const short int __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1263: erreur: invalid types ‘const short int __vector__[int]’ for array subscript
make[3]: *** [output/libyuv-i686-pc-linux-gnu/row_common.o] Erreur 1
make[3]: quittant le répertoire « /home/ccapelle/pjproject-2.5.5/third_party/build/yuv »
make[2]: *** [libyuv-i686-pc-linux-gnu.a] Erreur 2
make[2]: quittant le répertoire « /home/ccapelle/pjproject-2.5.5/third_party/build/yuv »
make[1]: *** [all] Erreur 1
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /home/ccapelle/pjproject-2.5.5/third_party/build »
make: *** [all] Erreur 1
```

Comment: The only solution I have found is to deactivate the lib as I'm not using the video:
./configure --disable-libyuv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to an answer: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1937

./configure --disable-libyuv

Comment: To be clear, it's OK to disable libyuv "if video is disabled".

Thanks for this.